# Using function as array variables in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Most of the time, when there is a function named func1 and it returns an array, I use this method to access a specific index of that returned array:

```
$myarray=func1();
echo $myarray['AssIndex'];
```

Is there a way to access it in a single line? Something like this?

```
// the brackets are not working. this is only to make my meaning clear.
echo {func1}['AssIndex'];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of PHP 5.4, you can do this:

```
echo func1()['AssIndex'];
```

This is called [Function Array Dereferencing](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing).

Comment: You are awesome and legen...wait for it... dary legendary!